# Запись запросов к скрипту

Tags: php

Вообщем есть такая форма:

```
<form method="post" action="http://site.ru/script.php">
<textarea rows="7" cols="30" name="text"></textarea>
<input type="image" src="http://site.ru/submit.png" alt="enter"></form>
```

Как мы видим, текст который мы ввели будет передаваться сюда: `http://site.ru/script.php`
Вопрос: можно ли сделать логирование запросов к `http://site.ru/script.php` (чтобы можно было видеть, кто какую форму отправлял). Извините за нубский вопрос, но все же жду адекватных ответов. Заранее большое спасибо! :)

Comment: Ну в принципе, сохраняй каждый пришедший $_POST массив  - вот тебе и лог. А вообще Apache ведет сам логи их можно глянуть в /var/log/apache[2]/aссess.log

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents('log.txt',serialize($_REQUEST)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: полностью поддерживаю, единственно что можно было бы добавить к сохраняемой информации время и IP пользователя